# how to go to the another viewcontroller after facebook login?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How to go to the another viewcontroller after facebook login? What should be done in Main.storyboard?

Here is my AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

import FBSDKCoreKit

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }

}
```

Here is ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        loginButton.center = self.view.center
        view.addSubview(loginButton)
    }

    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

        if error != nil {
         print("Something went wrong... \(error)" )
            return
        }

        print("Successfully logged in!")
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {

        print("Successfully logged out!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myViewController")
    self.navigationController?.push(vc, animated: true)
}
```

What that snippet does, is check whether the user is logged in via Facebook (I assume you're using the SDK), and if they are, instantiate a VC from the storyboard, and push it with the Navigation Controller. Where you want to put that, whether you want to present the VC in a different way, etc..., is up to you, as the flow of your app will heavily inform it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your ViewController.swift:

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
        if error == nil && !result.isCancelled{
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            if let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController(){
                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```